# Cache Manifest file is not expiring JavaScript file when forced update

Tags: javascript, html, caching, iis, cache-manifest

I'm testing out the HTML5 Cache Manifest file and am having a difficult time having it update JavaScript files. In Chrome, I can see that the manifest is updated whenever I make a change to the file and the browser downloads it but the JavaScript files specified in the manifest do not update.

I've tested it out and the reason behind this seems to be the HTTP Response Headers set in IIS. They have been set to expire web content after a specified duration. Am I incorrect in assuming that the files should update even if they haven't expired?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the HTTP Response Header "Expire Web content" to "Immediately" worked as I had intended it to. To my surprise, expiring immediately did not force pulling of the new files when the page was refreshed. After doing this, I performed the following steps to validate:

1) Cleaned browser cache

2) Loaded page for the first time

3) Altered a JavaScript file loaded with the page

4) Tried loading the page again (the browser still used the old JavaScript file)

5) Updated Cache Manifest

6) Tried loading page again, where the page loaded the old value but prompted the user that a newer version was available - when selected, the new file was utilized

Event trigger described in step 6 was taken from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/. Hope this helps someone else!